# checking current selection or value in a dropdown list using selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

HI

i was wondering if there is a way to check what is the current selected value in a drop down list using selenium ruby?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the verifySelectedX calls to do this.

So to check the label it would be 
`assert_equal "bar", @selenium.get_selected_label("foo")`

or to do the value of that item it would be 
`assert_equal "bar", @selenium.get_selected_value("foo")`